# orientdb resizing graph editor canvas

Tags: orientdb

using orientdb, I have a graph with lots of vertices.  The graph editor canvas seems to be stuck at one size--I can't resize it. Resizing the browser window has no effect, of course.  I can shrink the size of the vertex dots, but I need to be able to see the vertex labels.  Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks, Barbara

Comment: Consider providing some code samples to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling in the graph editor allows you to resize the canvas.